# Is there any way to use $http inside the config function or there is any way call the url inside config to get the value in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, angular-translate

I want to call the servlet inside the config function of angular js to get the accept language for that i am using $http inside config function is that possible or any alternate solutions please.As I am new to angular js

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Serrvices aren't available to inject directly in config. Can use them in `run()` if that helps. Need more detals about what exactly it is you need to do

Comment: You only can inject providers inside the config, but you can do a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm reading what do you ask, i think you can use a function inside your `.config()` and inside that function inject the services that you need.

i'll leave you an example using a function with `ui.router` so you can make an idea of how use it.

```
app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    var doSomething = function ($http, $cookies, myService) {
        //here all you logic
    }
    $stateProvider
        .state('myState', {
            url: '/',
            resolve: { doSomething: doSomething },//for example here you can use your function 
            templateUrl: "views/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginController'

        });

});
```

otherwise you can use `Providers` to inject on your `.config()` and use it.